# Can't manage to set text next to left floating image inside dialog

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

Probably a newbie question here but I'm having troubles to set text on the right of a `float: left` `<img>` inside a `md-dialog` :

```
<md-dialog aria-label="download" flex="60" ng-controller="viewerController">
    <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <h2>{{appName}}</h2>
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="answer('not applicable')">
                <md-icon md-svg-src="style/images/icons/ic_close_24px.svg"
                         aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-dialog-content>
        <div id="application">
            <md-list>
                <md-list-item>
                    <div style="font-size: 16px;">
                        <img style="float: left;margin: 0 5px 0 0; padding-bottom: 12px;"
                                 ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{appScreenshotBase64}}" 
                                 width="{{currentWidth * 0.35}}"/>
                        <h4><span class="fieldName">Technology : </span>{{appTechnology}}</h4>
                        <h4><span class="fieldName">Level : </span>{{appLevel}}</h4>
                        <h4><span class="fieldName">Development type</span> : </span>{{appDevType}}</h4>
                    </div>
                </md-list-item>
                <md-divider ></md-divider>

                <md-list-item class="md-1-line">
                    <div class="md-list-item-text">
                        <h4><span class="fieldName">Development type : </span>{{appDevType}}</h4>
                    </div>
                </md-list-item>
                <md-divider ></md-divider>
 <!-- ... -->
```

So my `md-dialog` width is set to 60% of the current width and the `<img>` to 35%. The 25% left inside the dialog should be more than enough to display my data (Technology, Level, Development type).

But instead, it goes to a new line under the `<img>` like this :
[image: Screenshot]

What do I need to change to make it work ?

Comment: Add `float: left` to the text container and also add `width`

Comment: Just as a side point but headings should not be used for styling

Comment: can you provide a fiddle.

Comment: Is this still ongoing?

Answer (score 0):

In general you should use the [layout attribute](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/layout/alignment) for this purpose.
If you want the child elements to be aligned next to each other add layout="row" to the container.